# How can the particle objects have different textures?

Tags: c++, directx, textures, hlsl, particles

I have a problem making particles, so I'm going to ask you a question. The problem is that when you make several particles, the texture of the particles is the texture of the particles made at the end. This is my code.

```
enter code herem_pParticleBuffer = new CStructuredBuffer;
m_pParticleBuffer->Create(sizeof(tParticle), m_iMaxParticle, nullptr);

m_pSharedBuffer = new CStructuredBuffer;
m_pSharedBuffer->Create(sizeof(tParticleShared), 1, nullptr);
m_pMesh = CResMgr::GetInst()->FindRes<CMesh>(L"PointMesh");
m_pMtrl = CResMgr::GetInst()->FindRes<CMaterial>(L"ParticleMtrl");
Ptr<CTexture> pParticle = _pTexture;
m_pMtrl->SetData(SHADER_PARAM::TEX_0, pParticle.GetPointer());
m_pUpdateMtrl = CResMgr::GetInst()->FindRes<CMaterial>(L"ParticleUpdateMtrl");
```

This is where the particles are initialized.

```
 float fRatio = tData[_in.iInstID].m_fCurTime / tData[_in.iInstID].m_fLifeTime;
float4 vCurColor = (g_vec4_1 - g_vec4_0) * fRatio + g_vec4_0;
return vCurColor * g_tex_0.Sample(g_sam_0, _in.vUV);
```

This is the hlsl corresponding to the pixel shader of the particles.